# How to convert varchar

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've the following statment:

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, DATEDIFF(day, t.date_of_birth, GETDATE())/365.25)
FROM tb_1 t
```

t.date_of_birth - varchar (20)

This query doesn't work.

> ERROR: function pg_catalog.date_diff("unknown", character varying,
>   timestamp without time zone) does not exist Hint: No function matches
>   the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type
>   casts.

How to fix it?

Comment: ERROR: ERROR: function pg_catalog.date_diff("unknown", character varying, timestamp without time zone) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
SELECT extract(day from now() - t.date_of_birth) FROM tb_1 t
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXTRACT_function.html

Comment: @KirillRodeonov please accept and/or upvote the answer